# Calculate PI recursively

Tags: java, math, recursion

[image: Formula (Mathematic background)]

I try to calculate PI with the following Method: (Java-Code)

```
private static double calculate(double k) {
    return (
            ( 3 * Math.pow(2, k-1) ) *
                    Math.sqrt(
                            2 - (2 * Math.sqrt(
                                    1-(
                                            Math.pow((calculate(k-1) / ( 3*Math.pow(2, k-1) )), 2)
                                    )
                            ))
                    )
    );
}
```

I get an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError on the line I try to call recursively the method itself.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Where is the end-condition?

Comment: your `calculate` method should have a break condition. I.e a condition when the calculation should be stopped. Otherwise you get recursive calls until the stack overflows.

Comment: There is none, so it will try to calculate insane - right?

Comment: if there's no break condition you just call calculate recursively until the stack is going full and you get stack overflow exception.

Comment: To get my point just try to go step by step your method on paper with a pencil. And you will realize what I mean.

Comment: Sorry for my dumbness, but I don't know how to implement an break condition to this - could you help me?

Comment: For example, at the start of `calculate` test if `k` is lower than a given constant and return a value for this k-approximation instead of calling `calculate` again and again.

Comment: Thanks - I finally solved it (: it was to easy to understand :P

Comment: If you have sorted this out, consider posting the fixed code as answer and accepting it

Comment: Note that the mathematical definition also needs a **break condition**. It's usually done by saying *"the first term `a_0` doesn't use the formula, it is just 1"* (or some other value). You also need to do this in your code like `if (input = ...) { return differentValue; } else { return formula(...); }`.

Comment: Ugly, awful code.  Think about style and readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it using tail recursion (dynamic programming) instead of simple recursion, as follows:

```
private static double calculate(double k) {
    double result = 3 * Math.sqrt(2);
    for(int i = 2; i <= k; i++)
       result = 3*Math.pow(2, k-1)*Math.sqrt(2-(2*Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(result / ( 3*Math.pow(2, k-1) ), 2)));
    return result;
}
```

In this approach, you did not need to be worry about stackoverflow. Besides, you have a good performance in implementation and running time such as you want in recursive implementation.